# asp repeater binding to sharepoint fields

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, asprepeater

I am trying to bind data from sharepoint list to an asp:repeater using c#.
The asp repeater has a sharepoint lookup field. How do i bind it?

I tried

```
    <SharePoint:LookupField runat="server" ID="TechQualificationLookup" ControlMode="Display" 
    Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TechQualificationLookup")%>'> 
    </SharePoint:LookupField>
```

but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: no error. it just comes out blank on the form. I am confused if this is how you bind to a sharepoint lookup field or is there another way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to bind SharePoint lookup field data into ASP.NET Repeater Control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptName" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
         <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>LookupTest</th>

        </tr>   
    </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td>
           <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LookupTest") %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>      
        </table><br />
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                using (SPSite site=new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                    SPList list = web.Lists["JerryList4"];
                    SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
                    rptName.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
                    rptName.DataBind();
                }

        }
```

[image]

Reference:

[Bind SharePoint Library Images Into Repeater Control Using ASP.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/bind-sharepoint-library-images-into-repeater-control-using-a/)

Comment: Thanks i will give this a try